# Cannot load static resources when using web fragments and spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, servlet-3.0, web-fragment

I have a main spring hello webapp, which has an include in the web.xml to include a web-fragment. I can't seem to get access tot he static resources in the jar, im using tomcat 7, servlet 3, Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE

and my jar structure is test.jar->META-INF->test.css

but when i load the app, the url:

http://localhost:8686/spring-fragment-test/test.css

does not seem to work, keep getting 404

i have configured as following:

Spring.xml in the main app

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fragments" />
```

with the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <absolute-ordering>   
    <name>SampleFragment</name>
    </absolute-ordering>    

</web-app>
```

my other fragemt jar has the following xml in the meta-inf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-fragment id="WebFragment_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>SampleFragment</display-name> 
    <name>SampleFragment</name> 

</web-fragment>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are putting the location "/resources/" in the xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

You have to  put your css file in the section

Web-Content/resources/(css file)

You can now access the file by writing

http://loclahost:8080/spring/resources/main.css

Comment: Tell me the exact structure where you are putting that css.

Comment: I have changed that answer. try that

Comment: Yes i tried that, but i want to pick up the css in the Jar file, which i cant seem to do....

Comment: well i got a little further y adding the following

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" /> 

but then i dont need the web-fragment.xml ?!?

Comment: dunno... I dont have any idea what it is about? Although I can say that program should work without it.

Comment: If there are 100+ project jars, then in which jar's web-fragment should one put the static resources?